# OkHttp getting all cookies

Tags: java, okhttp

I am logging into a website with OkHttp. From browser inspection I know that the initial response is a 302 redirect and I should end up with 4 cookies:

[image]

However my attempts so far to show the cookies I receive indicate a 200 response and only JSESSION ID cookie is printed.

```
    // COOKIE HANDLER
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    
    // INTERCEPTOR
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    // PROXY
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));

    // NEW CLIENT
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .proxy(proxy)
        .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator)
        .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler))
        .addInterceptor(logging)
        .build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("user", "pass")
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://www.contoso.com")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.code());

    CookieStore cookieStore = cookieManager.getCookieStore();

    for (HttpCookie cookie : cookieStore.getCookies()) {
        System.out.println("\n Cookie:" + cookie.getName());
        System.out.println("\t Domain:" + cookie.getDomain());
        System.out.println("\t Value:" + cookie.getValue());
    }
```

Is the redirect what is causing me not to see all the cookies and is there a way to capture all the cookies? I presume it has something to do with the 302.

How to check what is in cookieHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [loadForRequest](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cookie-jar/load-for-request/) on the CookieJar. That’ll give you all the cookies it knows about for your target URL.

Comment: Do you have a example that would print to console?  How is that different to the for statement?